# Problem with upgrading of libraries (spring) in JAVA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-commons

My project contains a lot libraries and I want update following:

spring from 5.0.10.RELASE to 5.3.18 or higher
spring-content
spring-core
spring-beans
spring-aop
spring-context-support
spring-orm
spring-jdb
spring-web
spring-webmvc
spring-tx

---

spring-data-jpa from  to 2.3.2 or higher
spring-data-commons  from  to 2.3.2 or higher

But when I changed version my project durring start has a many errors.
How can I check that these verions libraires are compatible with other (hibernate, log4j etc..)

Answer (score 0):

remove all version tags of spring in your pom and create a dependency management as following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```